# Custom Rollup Field without Object relationship

Tags: apex

I have two object - Object A and Object B. Object A has a field "Total Amount" and Object B has a field "Amount". Both objects have NO relation with each other. What I want to do is bring in total SUM of "Amount" (from Object B) in "Total Amount" (of Object A) using trigger. Can some one please help me with an example?

```
    trigger RollupTrigger on Object_B__c (after insert,after update)
{
        Decimal decValue = 0;

   AggregateResult[] groupedResults = [SELECT  SUM(Amount__c)   FROM Object_B__c  GROUP BY ID];

for (AggregateResult ar : groupedResults)  {
    System.debug('Average amount' + ar.get('expr0'));


    For (Object_A__c A : [SELECT ID, Total_Amount__c from Object_A__c WHERE ID = 'a122800000154Mi'])
    {

        A.Total_Amount__c += (Decimal)ar.get('expr0');
        Update A;

       }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the use case here. With no relationship how would you know which records to sum? Will it always be the sum of all records in object b?

Comment: Hi Eric, it always be the sum of all records in object b.

Comment: I would use a custom setting then. On insert or update of object b records recalc and populate the custom setting. Then for object a on before insert and update populate using custom setting. Would give best performance if obj b does not change often. May be overkill to all depends on your specifics

Comment: Thanks Eric. Issue is not with 'how to save it?' rather its 'How to do it?'. I`m trying to use SUM aggregate function in my trigger and it fails. Could you pls give me an example? Please see my edited code above.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Hi Eric, thanks for all the help. I have updated my code. Code only works if Total_Amount__c has some value in it. If I remove a value, I keep getting - [System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object: Trigger.RollupTrigger: line 14, column 1]

Comment: See updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amount is not a valid field for a custom object

Most likely is should be `Amount__c`

Per your updated comment this will solve the NPE

```
A.Total_Amount__c += (Decimal)ar.get('expr0') == null ? 0 : (Decimal)ar.get('expr0');
```